# Auto width of flex column

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I set the width of first flex column so that its width is only the size of its content?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.inside {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">Right</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrKkOW

Setting `width: auto` doesn't work... Something like `flex-basis: content` would be nice to have.

Answer (score 32):

Don't give that column `flex:1` as it will expand to take up as much room as is permitted.

In fact, don't give it any flex value at all and it will default to `width:auto`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.inside {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.inside-right {
  flex: 1;
  background:#c0ffee;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIght</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIght</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left Left Left LeftLeft LeftLeft Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIghtRIghtRIght</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: It seems the intention was to have every "left" element be the same size.

This is not possible with flexbox but CSS Tables can achieve this.

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.inside {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.inside-left {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIght</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIght</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left Left Left LeftLeft LeftLeft Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIghtRIghtRIght</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but is it possible to make all left columns the same width, the width of the longest one? That was my intent why I thought flex could be good idea to use :)

Comment: No, that's not possible with flexbox. You can do that with CSS table layout though. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xEzagW

Answer (score 10):

You have to restructure your HTML a bit to achieve what you want:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.inside {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.flex-grow {
  flex: 1;
}
.inside-right {
  background:#c0ffee;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div class="inside">Left</div>
    <div class="inside">Left Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
    <div class="inside">Left Left Left LeftLeft LeftLeft Left Left LeftLeft Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="inside inside-right">Right</div>
    <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIght</div>
    <div class="inside inside-right">RIghtRIghtRIght RIghtRIghtRIght</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works only if the total width less than the width of the <body>. As soon as on of the Right cells become so wide that they don't fit in a single line, this (transposed) design falls apart.

Comment: Good point. If this is something to consider, then you need to choose another solution (like an actual table or a grid)

Answer (score 5):

If you want each column to be as wide as its content you need to use align-item: flex-start
check this link [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays `width: fit-content;` is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=width%3A%20fit-content%3B), so setting fit-content to the first element will do the thing.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.inside {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.inside-left {
  width: fit-content;
}

.inside-right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="inside inside-left">Left</div>
  <div class="inside inside-right">RIght</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you solve this problem with `width: fit-content`? Can you give an example?

Comment: @YingYang Sure, updated my answer with a snippet

Comment: Note that a lack of an accepted answer does not necessarily indicate OP is still waiting for solution, unsatisfied. Likewise the reverse (an accepted answer being present) does not preclude users from adding _new_ answers with newer or better methods.

Comment: @TylerH Certainly, also the lack of activity from the OP can be a reason... "Last seen more than 1 year ago"

Comment: @la_petite_kozel Thanks for the snippet. However, that doesn't solve the author's problem of setting **every** left column to the width of the widest column (like in a table, see the other answers). Still an interesting suggestion, I didn't know about `width: fit-content;` before.